# Fastest Grown Lettuce

Tags: vegetables, greenhouse, lettuce

I was wondering if there was a "world record" of the fastest fully grown Lettuce and how fast it grew, is there a record for it? or just how fast would it in theory be?

Comment: The fastest growing lettuce varieties are "leaf lettuce" and you can't really define what "fully grown" means for a plant where you can harvest individual leaves. You can expect to *start* harvesting after about 30 days.

Comment: malobar spinach takes off once it gets going